# How can I debug Azure Functions using .NET 5 (isolated process) in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, azure-functions, .net-5

I've recently migrated from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5.0 ([using isolated/out-of-process runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide)) for an Azure Function project in C#. Everything is working as expected. However, whenever I debug, none of my breakpoints hits. Why can't I debug my Azure Function app now, but I used to be able to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio Version 16.10 or later, debugging in Visual Studio is straightforward.

[The updated steps from Microsoft are as follows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-developer-howtos?tabs=browser&pivots=development-environment-vs#run-the-function-locally):

> Visual Studio integrates with Azure Functions Core Tools so that you
> can test your functions locally using the full Azure Functions
> runtime.
>
> - To run your function, press F5 in Visual Studio. You might need to enable a firewall exception so that the tools can handle HTTP
>   requests. Authorization levels are never enforced when you run a
>   function locally.
> - Copy the URL of your function from the Azure Functions runtime output and run the request. A welcome to Functions message is
>   displayed when the function runs successfully and logs are written to
>   the runtime output.
> - To stop debugging, press Shift+F5 in Visual Studio.
>
> After you've verified that the function runs correctly on your local
> computer, it's time to publish the project to Azure.

---

**This below section only applies if you are using Visual Studio Version 16.9 or earlier. I highly recommend upgrading Visual Studio instead of using this "PITA" method.**

(Please [see the answer from Andrii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67628240/11530367) for an alternative solution)

After  doing a deal of research online, I've learned that the isolated process used by .NET 5 for Azure Functions doesn't support debugging by default. To do so in Visual Studio, [you need to follow these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-developer-howtos?tabs=browser&pivots=development-environment-vs#run-the-function-locally) (link used to be valid, but has since been updated).

1. Open your solution in Visual Studio
2. Open PowerShell within Visual Studio (View -> Terminal, or Ctrl-`)
3. Navigate to your project `cd MyProject`
4. Start the function with debugging enabled `func start –-dotnet-isolated-debug`
   At this point, you should see a PID printed in the terminal output that looks similar to the following

```
 Functions:
     HttpExample: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpExample
 For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
 [2021-03-09T08:41:41.904Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 81720) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
```

5. Open the Attach Process (Open -> Debug) window, and select the PID found in the console output
   At this point, the breakpoints are now valid and will be hit.

Answer (score 7):

**No longer required as the native Visual Studio support already added**

There is an easy way!

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Debugger.Launch(); // The trick! <<=======================================

        using var host = new HostBuilder()
...
```

Then just launch as usual without debugging (Ctrl+F5) and attach the same Visual Studio instance to `dotnet` process
[image: Attach debugger]

And voila, you debug your function!

Comment: Hello @Andrii - I saw that Visual Studio has been updated to debugging is supported without these additional steps, so I updated my answer and marked it as correct. Just wanted to let you know it changed.