# Unable to debug Azure Function that targets .NET 5.0

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, .net-5

I wrote a simple Azure Function from the template using the .NET CORE 3.1 as target framework.

After that I migrated the target framework to .NET 5.0 using the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide)

After the migration I'm not able to debug the Azure Function. I get the usual message "the breakpoint will not currently be hit".

The csproj is this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

local.settings.json is this:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
      "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

program.cs is this:

```
class Program
{
    static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
                        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                        .ConfigureServices(s =>
                        {
                        })
                        .Build();

        return host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

The simple function is:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;

namespace FunctionAppNet50
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [Function("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            var response = req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this related to the ".NET isolated process" model or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Check out  [this blog post](https://www.daveabrock.com/2021/02/24/functions-dotnet-5/) - Dave explains in the paragraph "About the tooling" that the tooling isn't quite on a par with the .NET Core 3.x version. You *can* debug locally - it's just a tad more involved to get it to work

Comment: Possibly duplicate (with answers on how to work around the limitations): https://stackoverflow.com/q/67526631/1149773

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks... found the solution in the suggested articles by marc_c and Douglas.

1. I installed the Azure Function Core Tools using choco with the command "choco install azure-functions-core-tools-3";
2. run the function in a shell with "func start –-dotnet-isolated-debug";
3. attached the debugger at the PID showed in the window

here is an article that similar steps: https://dev.to/kenakamu/debug-net-5-function-with-visual-studio-visual-studio-code-5235

Comment: There is an easier way from the answer of the similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/67628240/1149328